# ECK Filebeat Autodiscover Filter by Kubernetes Namespace

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, filebeat

I wish to filter Filebeat autodiscover using Kubernetes Namespaces.

Kubernetes is running on EKS v1.20.7

ECK versions:

- Elasticsearch v7.7.0
- Kibana v7.7.0
- Filebeat v7.10.0

Filtering is not working based on the following config:

```
filebeatConfig:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: ${NODE_NAME}
          hints.enabled: true
          templates:
          - condition.or:
              - equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: "ingress"
              - equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: "kube-system"
            config:
              - type: container
                paths:
                  - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/${data.kubernetes.container.id}-json.log
                exclude_lines: ["^\\s+[\\-`('.|_]"]

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata: ~
      - add_host_metadata: ~

    cloud:
      id: '${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}'
    cloud:
      auth: '${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}'

    output:
      elasticsearch:
        enabled: true
        hosts: "elasticsearch-es-http.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9200"
        username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
        password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
        protocol: https
        ssl:
          verification_mode: "none"

    setup.ilm.enabled: auto
    setup.ilm.rollover_alias: "filebeat-testing-v8-%{[agent.version]}"
    setup.ilm.pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
```

Then when the index is queried via the Dev Console it returns both the "ingress" and "monitoring" namespaces, which it shouldn't.

Query:

```
GET filebeat-testing-v8-7.10.0-2021.09.29-000001/_search 
{ // Identify all Kubernetes namespaces in this Filebeat index
  "size": 0, // Don't return any documents, just aggregation
  "aggs" : {
    "distinctValues" : { 
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "kubernetes.namespace", // Field to be aggregated
        "size" : 5000000 // How many unique values to return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "distinctValues" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "monitoring",
          "doc_count" : 25093
        },
        {
          "key" : "ingress",
          "doc_count" : 6041
        },
        {
          "key" : "kube-system",
          "doc_count" : 132
        },
        {
          "key" : "vault-agent",
          "doc_count" : 9
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas or pointers on why this is not filtering correctly, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The working config is :

```
filebeatConfig:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: ${NODE_NAME}
          hints.enabled: true
          templates:
            - config:
                - type: container
                  paths:
                    - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/${data.kubernetes.container.id}-json.log
                  exclude_lines: ["^\\s+[\\-`('.|_]"]
                  processors:
                    - drop_event.when.not.or:
                        - equals.kubernetes.namespace: "ingress"
                        - equals.kubernetes.namespace: "kube-system"

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata: ~
      - add_host_metadata: ~

    cloud:
      id: '${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}'
    cloud:
      auth: '${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}'

    output:
      elasticsearch:
        enabled: true
        hosts: "elasticsearch-es-http.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9200"
        username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
        password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
        protocol: https
        ssl:
          verification_mode: "none"

    setup.ilm.enabled: auto
    setup.ilm.rollover_alias: "filebeat-testing-v8-%{[agent.version]}"
    setup.ilm.pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
```